# What's better approach? SQL select for one by one or all together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Well, the title might look confusing, but - I need to Select one field from SQL database from each user based on their email. The thing is - there might be multiple occurrences of each user, so simple query

```sql
Select Table.Field From Table Where Table.Email='email@email.com'
```

might return multiple rows of this field (don't ask me why, I did not design the system).
What is better approach if I get request for multiple `Table.Email`'s?

1. Make selection

```sql
Select Table.Field From Table
Where Table.Email='email@email.com'
      or
      Table.Email='email2@email.com'
      or
      Table.Email='email3@email.com'
      or
      ...
```

and then iterate over all results and control what value has the `Table.Field` for each `Table.Email`?

2. For-each Email I get perform

```sql
Select Table.Field From Table Where Table.Email=Email
```

So there would be as many selects as emails I receive.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Do not spam taags . Why you've used `python`?

Comment: Well the app is built in python, but nevermind, I deleted it

Comment: I would try to minimize the number of SQL queries to 1, regardless of the query length, also try cache when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to parse.

For example, you said you might get multiple rows for the "field" (column). But can the value of the column for each of those rows be different? And if so, how do want to decide which of the values you want?

```
select table.email, max(table.column) from table where table.email in ('email1', 'email2', ...) group by table.email?

select table.email, min(table.column) from table where table.email in ('email1', 'email2', ...) group by table.email ?
```

Neither of your proposed solutions address the stated problem, if what you're trying to do is get a single value for the "field" based on each email argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IN` clause to filter on multiple values,

```
Select Table.Field From Table Where Table.Email in ('email@email.com' , 
'email2@email.com' , 'email3@email.com , ....)
```

`OR` can be used only whenever you are filtering the values satisfying either or conditions with multiple columns.

Comment: Your query syntax is invalid, and your claim is incorrect. `select * from T where C in(1, 2, 3)` is functionally identical to `select * from T where C = 1 or C = 2 or C = 3`

Comment: Even though it provides same result, the way of Sql standard to defile `OR` clause is incorrect. When you want to filter with same column with multiple values, `IN` cause is the right way. Using `OR` for same column will also impact the perfomnce

Comment: No. it's perfectly correct, and exactly the same. [In gets compiled into or](https://i.imgur.com/RDVXc4C.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is better to do bulk processing in the database rather than in the application.  The reason is simple:  Each query has overhead for preparing the query itself and for returning results.  Multiple queries multiplies this overhead.

Second, if you query each email separately, you run the risk of returning multiple rows for each email -- unless you structure the query well.  In SQL itself, you can limit the result to one per email using either aggregation, `row_number()`, or a similar mechanism.  For instance:

```
select email, field
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by email order by createdAt desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where email in (< emails you want here >)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

There are some cases where you might want to fetch each email separately.  For instance, if you were running an expensive operation separately on each row -- such as sending an email -- then it might make sense to interleave the operations.  In this case, the "bulk" query has more overhead because it needs to process more data, so the time to the first result is faster by looking for a single email.

However, the general rule is to let the database do as much work on the data as appropriate for the database.